# How to automate starting the ssh agent and adding my key(s) in WSL2 for Windows 11

Tags: ssh, windows-11, wsl2, ssh-agent

```
OS: Windows 11 Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
WSL version: 1.2.5.0 (WSL 2)
Linux distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
```

I run WSL2 on Windows 11 in a Windows Terminal window, and I often connect to a remote server through ssh key authentication. To do that, each time I open a new Windows Terminal window (or even just a new tab in an existing Terminal) I need to execute

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key
```

(it's a key without a passphrase). This gets old very quickly. Is there a way that I can automate the launch of the ssh agent, and the addition of my key to it, every time I start a  WSL2 session in the Windows Terminal?

Comment: If it's without passphrase, do you _need_ the agent at all, as opposed to having the ssh client load it directly from a file?

Comment: I feel I must be missing a nuance to your question -- You obviously know about adding commands to ~/.bashrc` as I see in your previous questions that you've been using WSL (as well as the Mac command-line) for a few years now.

Comment: @u1686_grawity maybe I don't need the agent. So what should I do?

Comment: The agent is useful when you're using the option `AddKeysToAgent`. It gives you a "grace period", remembering the password for a specified time. I'm still trying to make this work on WSL, but it seems complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Better Alternative (than original answer) based on having no passphrase on the keyfile

You asked about [@u1686_grawity's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1808572/how-to-automate-starting-the-ssh-agent-and-adding-my-keys-in-wsl2-for-windows/1808594#comment2838851_1808572):

> If it's without passphrase, do you need the agent at all, as opposed to having the ssh client load it directly from a file?

@u1686_grawity makes a good point, and that's that most SSH clients will let you specify a keyfile directly without requiring an agent.

> I often connect to a remote server through ssh key authentication.

You don't necessarily mention how you are connecting, but if it's with the stock `ssh` command, then you can simply specify your keyfile on the commandline with:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key <username>@site
```

In that case, you don't need an `ssh-agent` running at all.

Even if you aren't using `ssh`-proper, most SSH tools that are based on OpenSSH will also use the same `~/.ssh/config`, meaning you can even skip specifying the identity filename.  For example, create a `~/.ssh/config` with:

```
Host <whatever_you_want_to_call_it>
  Hostname <hostname_or_ip>
  User <optional_username_if_different>
  IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/my_key
```

Then you can simply `ssh <whatever_you_want_to_call_it>` and everything else will be pulled from the config.  Other tools like `sftp` and `scp` will also act the same.

##### Old Answer (works as well, but required for keys will passwords):

@Kolkhis's answer will certainly work, but if you run multiple shells (e.g., under Tmux or Windows Terminal), it will invoke a new running instance of `ssh-agent` for each shell.  In your case, that's not too bad since your key doesn't have a password (although I would caution against that as well, of course).  However, for keys with passwords, you have to enter it again for each shell you run.  It will also incur additional (albeit small) startup time and memory.

I recommend the [`keychain` utility](https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain) by Daniel Robbins (also the creator of Gentoo Linux).  This small utility checks to see if there's an existing `ssh-agent` running, and if so, it simply sets the appropriate environment variables to point to that agent.  Otherwise, on first launch, of course, it will start a new agent.

It's available in the default repositories of most distributions, including Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Then add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
eval $(keychain --eval my_key)
```

IIRC, you don't even need to specify the path to the key unless it *isn't* in the the default `~/.ssh/`.

Comment: since my key doesn't have a passphrase, is it possible to have the ssh client load it directly without using the ssh-agent? User  @u1686_grawity suggested it, but I'm not sure how it works. Should I just add `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key` to the `.bashrc`?

Comment: @DeltaIV Either way, you'll also need the `ssh-agent` line from the other answer in each shell invocation, so I still recommend `keychain`, which will prevent multiple copies from running.

Comment: @DeltaIV Ah, I see the comment you are referring to now.  I'll edit my answer to add some detail there.

Comment: @DeltaIV And apologies - It seems likely that the suggestion that u1686_grawity made is the easiest.  The rest of us (myself included) were overthinking it with the need for an agent.

Answer (score 3):

The `.bashrc` solution proposed by others will spawn a new agent every time you open a new terminal window. I wanted to fix this without resorting to third-party tools. So this was my first attempt:

~/.bash_profile:

```sh
ssh_pid=$(pidof ssh-agent)

if [ "$ssh_pid" = "" ]; then
        eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi
```

Unfortunately, on WSL every new terminal window spawns a new environment, so there's no way, as far as I know, to set the environment for all terminals.

I noticed the socket file previously pointed to by `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` still exists, and the agent is still running. That's good, and it shows we just need to fix the environment.

Here's the final solution, which preserves the original environment and restores it every time you open a new terminal:

~/.bash_profile:

```sh
ssh_pid=$(pidof ssh-agent)

# If the agent is not running, start it, and save the environment to a file
if [ "$ssh_pid" = "" ]; then
        ssh_env="$(ssh-agent -s)"
        echo "$ssh_env" | head -n 2 | tee ~/.ssh_agent_env > /dev/null
fi

# Load the environment from the file
if [ -f ~/.ssh_agent_env ]; then
        eval "$(cat ~/.ssh_agent_env)"
fi
```

This creates a file (`~/.ssh_agent_env`) to store the environment, and use it to reset the variables every time a new terminal is started. This ensures only one instance of the agent is running.

Also note that this code will not output anything - it's completely silent.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add those two lines to your `.bashrc` file.

Open an instance of your WSL2, and put the following at the end of your `~/.bashrc`. You can use any text editor to do this - vi/vim, ed, nano, etc.

```bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key
```

Alternatively, if you have a `~/.bash_aliases` file, you could add it there instead.

After you've done that, you can use the command `exec bash -l` to reload bash and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm going to propose a slightly different method in an answer ;-)

Comment: Right now, the problem with this is that the required environment variables (e.g. SSH_AGENT_PID, SSH_AUTH_SOCK) are emptied (lost) after you close the first terminal. You can kill the agent with `killall ssh-agent`, but you'll lose the keys stored in it, specially if they're added with the option `AddKeysToAgent`.